# Groovy++ error when adding @Typed

Tags: groovy, groovy++

I was interested in testing performance gain for groovy++ over plain groovy.
I found the script to test

```
class Chain
{
    def size
    def first

    def init(siz)
    {
        def last
        size = siz
        for(def i = 0 ; i < siz ; i++)
        {
            def current = new Person()
            current.count = i
            if (i == 0) first = current
            if (last != null)
            {
                last.next = current
            }
            current.prev = last
            last = current
        }
        first.prev = last
        last.next = first
    }

    def kill(nth)
    {
        def current = first
        def shout = 1
        while(current.next != current)
        {
            shout = current.shout(shout,nth)
            current = current.next
        }
        first = current
    }
}

class Person
{
    def count
    def prev
    def next

    def shout(shout,deadif)
    {
        if (shout < deadif)
        {
            return (shout + 1)
        }
        prev.next = next

        next.prev = prev
        return 1
    }
}

def main(args)
{
    println "Starting"
    def ITER = 100000
    def start = System.nanoTime()
    for(def i = 0 ; i < ITER ; i++)
    {
        def chain = new Chain()
        chain.init(40)
        chain.kill(3)
    }
    def end = System.nanoTime()
    println "Total time = " + ((end - start)/(ITER * 1000)) + " microseconds"
}
```

It works. But if I try to add

```
@Typed
```

before first class name and run I'm getting error:

**#groovy groovy.groovy**

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/home/melco/test/groovy.groovy: 18: Cannot find property next of class Object
 @ line 18, column 22.
                   last.next = current
                        ^

1 error
```

**# groovy -version**

Groovy Version: 1.7.5 JVM: 1.6.0_18

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enjoy statically typed compilation you need to provide at least some amount of type information.

Normally it is enough to define types of properties (next, prev in your case) and types of method parameters.

Comment: See https://github.com/alextkachman/groovypp/blob/master/Examples/src/Iterations.groovy

Comment: In general Groovy++ Google Group is more natural place for such questions. See http://groups.google.com/group/groovyplusplus?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

All the variables you declare are of type java.lang.Object (Or grovy.lang.Object in this case). So they don't have the methods "next" etc.

Try to use `Person current = new Person()` and `Cain current = first` etc.